# Always include first line in grep

Tags: bash, grep

I often grep CSV files with column names on the first line. Therefore, I want the output of grep to always include the first line (to get the column names) as well as any lines matching the grep pattern. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could include an alternate pattern match for the one of the column names. If a column was called **COL** then this would work:

```
$ grep -E 'COL|pattern' file.csv
```

Comment: It might also match an unintended line later in the file, if you didn't have strict control over the contents of the first line.

Answer (score 86):

#### sed:

```
sed '1p;/pattern/!d' input.txt
```

#### awk:

```
awk 'NR==1 || /pattern/' input.txt
```

#### grep1:

```
grep1() { awk -v pattern="${1:?pattern is empty}" 'NR==1 || $0~pattern' "${2:-/dev/stdin}"; }
```

Comment: Note the sed version shows the first line twice. Use `'1{p;d};` instead of `1p;` to avoid this.

Comment: I like that sed can be used, I'd just never suggest its quirky syntax to a newbie.  The awk version is easier to explain, and the sed one is notably harder to get right.  The instant errors with :? in the function are pretty cool, though.

Comment: To print **multiple lines** from the begging: `sed '1,3p;/pattern/!d'`
or `awk 'NR<4 || /pattern/'` - Will print the first 3 lines.

Comment: How could `grep1` be tweaked so that `kubectl get pods -n foo | grep1 bar` works instead of returning `filename is empty` ?

Comment: How would one modify the `grep1` version to take a third argument (defaulting to 1) which is the number of header lines it should include? 
Use case: Some commands output two or more header lines, e.g. `netstat` or `systemctl status`. It would be useful to be able to pipe the output of those commands to such a version of `grep1`.

Answer (score 21):

grep doesn't really have a concept of line number, but awk does, so here's an example to output lines contain "Incoming" - and the first line, whatever it is:

```
awk 'NR == 1 || /Incoming/' foo.csv
```

You could make a script (a bit excessive, but).  I made a file, grep+1, and put this in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
pattern="$1" ; shift
exec awk 'NR == 1 || /'"$pattern"'/' "$@"
```

Now one can:

```
./grep+1 Incoming
```

edit: removed the "{print;}", which is awk's default action.

Comment: Howdy, Alex -- I like the script idea, but might modify it slightly to actually use grep instead of awk such that grep's other command-line arguments could be used: `read; printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"; grep "$@"`. Main gotcha with this approach is that if the args include filename(s), one would need to parse them out for local handling.

Comment: An easier way to deal with the quoting: `awk -v patt="$pattern" 'NR==1 || $0 ~ patt'`

Comment: Right Charles.  A good solution would preserve all of grep's options, and both reading from stdin or from filenames.  However, the question sounds more like looking for a one-liner, even a broken one like another offered with uses $2 for the filename (so it only works on exactly 1 file) but trades that out for error feedback.

Comment: Glenn: on the "-v" - the asker didn't include his Unix variant.  Do all versions of grep have -v ? :-)

Comment: @AlexNorth-Keys, that's `awk -v`, and yes, that functionality is included in the [One True Awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk/blob/master/main.c#L123) and is [in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html). And of course, `grep -v` is [in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) too. :)

Answer (score 12):

Another option:

```
$ cat data.csv | (read line; echo "$line"; grep SEARCH_TERM)
```

Example:

```
$ echo "title\nvalue1\nvalue2\nvalue3" | (read line; echo "$line"; grep value2)
```

Output:

```
title
value2
```

Comment: A very simple and elegant solution, still using grep, no need to create function or 'hack'.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `sed` instead of `grep` to do this:

```
sed -n -e '1p' -e '/pattern/p' < $FILE
```

This will print the first line twice, however, if it happens to contain the pattern.

`-n` tells `sed` not to print each line by default.
`-e '1p'` prints the first line.
`-e '/pattern/p'` prints each line that matches the pattern.

Comment: Use `;` to sep: `sed -n '1p;/pattern/p'`

Comment: If the first line contains the pattern, won't it be printed twice?

Comment: `sed '1b;/pattern/!d'` would solve the `print the first line twice` problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very general solution, for example if you want to sort a file while keeping the first line in place. Basically, *"pass the first line through as-is, then do whatever I want (`awk`/`grep`/`sort`/whatever) on the rest of the data."*

Try this in a script, perhaps calling it `keepfirstline` (don't forget `chmod +x keepfirstline` and to put it in your `PATH`):

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='' read -r JUST1LIINE
printf "%s\n" "$JUST1LIINE"
exec "$@"
```

It can be used as follows:

```
cat your.data.csv | keepfirstline grep SearchTerm > results.with.header.csv
```

or perhaps, if you want to filter with `awk`

```
cat your.data.csv | keepfirstline awk '$1 < 3' > results.with.header.csv
```

I often like to sort a file, but keeping the header in the first line

```
cat your.data.csv | keepfirstline sort
```

`keepfirstline` executes the command it's given (`grep SearchTerm`), but only after reading and printing the first line.

Comment: Thanks! is there a way to preserve to grep red coloring?

Comment: `grep --color=yes` should for grep to be colourful no matter what. You might find that `grep --color` is sufficient in many cases

Comment: Do you think that `read` reads just the first line from `stdin`, not more? I.e. reads it character by character without buffering? I do not think so. I think that the command invoked by `exec` would get incomplete input remaining on `stdin` because `bash` will read more than just the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
head -1 <filename>
```

and then execute `grep`

Comment: Incomplete. You would also want to combine the output in to a single stream (execute inside a group or subshell), and you'd want to ensure that the `grep` doesn't accidentally match the first line of the file as well.

Comment: yes, of course, but u can just do `head -1 <filename>` together with `tail -1 +1 | grep ...` - seems much simpler than many ideas here - that's all I was saying

Answer (score 0):

So, I posted a completely different short answer above a while back.

However, for those pining for a command that looks like grep in terms of taking all the same options (although this script requires you to use the long options if an optarg is involved), and can cope with weird characters in filenames, etc, etc.. have fun pulling this apart.

Essentially it's a grep that always emits the first line.  If you think a file with no matching lines should skip emitting that first (header) line, well, that's left as an exercise for the reader.  I saved is as `grep+1`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# grep+1 [<option>...] [<regex>] [<file>...]
# Emits the first line of each input and ignores it otherwise.
# For grep options that have optargs, only the --forms will work here.

declare -a files options
regex_seen=false
regex=

double_dash_seen=false
for arg in "$@" ; do
    is_file_or_rx=true
    case "$arg" in
        -*) is_file_or_rx=$double_dash_seen ;;
    esac
    if $is_file_or_rx ; then
        if ! $regex_seen ; then
            regex="$arg"
            regex_seen=true
        else
            files[${#files[*]}]="$arg"     # append the value
        fi
    else
        options[${#options[*]}]="$arg"     # append the value       
    fi
done

# We could either open files all at once in the shell and pass the handles into
# one grep call, but that would limit how many we can process to the fd limit.
# So instead, here's the simpler approach with a series of grep calls

if $regex_seen ; then
    if [ ${#files[@]} -gt 0 ] ; then
        for file in "${files[@]}" ; do
            head -n 1 "$file"
            tail -n +2 "$file" | grep --label="$file" "${options[@]}" "$regex" 
        done
    else
        grep "${options[@]}"   # stdin
    fi
else
    grep "${options[@]}"   # probably --help
fi

#--eof
```

Comment: Duffy should enjoy this.

Answer (score 0):

All answer were correct. Just another idea for situations to grep the output of a command (and not a file) including the first line could be done like this ;-)

```
df -h | grep -E '(^Filesystem|/mnt)'  # <<< returns usage of devices, with mountpoint '/mnt/...'
ps aux | grep -E '(^USER|grep)'       # <<< returns all grep-process
```

The `-E` option of grep enables its regex-mode. The string we grep uses `|` and can be interpretated as an "or", so we look in the `df`-exmaple for lines:

- starting with `Filesystem` (leading '^' in the first sub expression means "line starts with")
- and lines, that contains `/mnt`

Another, way could be to pipe the output into a `tempfile` and to grep the content like shown in other posts. This can be helpful, if you don't know the content of the first line.

```
head -1 <file> && grep ff <file>
```

Answer (score 0):

For files

```
head -n 1 file.csv ; grep MyValue file.csv
```

For commands

```
ps -aux | (head -n 1 ; grep index) | grep -v grep
```

For watch

```
watch "ps -aux | (head -n 1 ; grep index) | grep -v grep"
```